# dbBind function error when trying to set up parameterized query on SQL Server

Tags: r, r-dbi

I am trying to do some parameterized queries using the `DBI` package `dbSendQuery`, `dbBind` and `dbFetch` workflow.

I am able to use the `dbSendQuery` using `?` as a placeholder for a variable. however, when I run `dbBind` I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbBind' for signature '"Microsoft SQL Server"'
```

The whole of my code looks like this:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
test_connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                                  Driver = "SQL Server",
                                  Server = "MyServer",
                                  Database = "MyDataBase")
test_query <- dbSendQuery(test_connection,
                          "SELECT TOP 2 col1, col2 FROM MyTable WHERE col2 = ?")
dbBind(test_connection,
       list('value'))

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
            unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbBind' for signature '"Microsoft SQL Server"'
```

Can anyone explain to me the reason for this error?

If I hard code `value` in the `dbSendQuery` statement and use `dbFetch` the query does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dbBind` you should use the query object instead of the connection object. In your example:

```
dbBind(test_query, list('value'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this solution and was like "obviously I didn't make that mistake it must have been a typo" - Turns out I did. Thanks for for finding this in the archive.